# Upload with Nodejs : wrong file sent with response.end

Tags: node.js, vagrant, ubuntu-server, formidable, fontforge

I'm trying to upload a file and convert it with fontforge, to send it back to user, all these with formidable.
My code worked on my first machine, but then I created an Ubuntu-Server VM with Vagrant, SSHed on it, DLed fontforge, formidable (and nodejs basically), and retried.
That's what my **server.js** file looks like:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
http = require('http'),
exec = require("child_process").exec,
fs = require("fs");


http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log(files);
    console.log(fields);
    exec("fontforge -script convert.sh -format \"." + fields.format + "\"" + " " + files.upload.path, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + files.upload.name.replace('svg', fields.format));
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-font-' + fields.format});
        res.end(files.upload.path + "." + fields.format);
        fs.unlink(files.upload.path, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('successfully deleted ' + files.upload.path);
        });
        fs.unlink(files.upload.path + "." + fields.format, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('successfully deleted ' + files.upload.path + "." + fields.format);
        });

      });
    });

    return;
}).listen(8080);
```

The form appears correctly on the client (some basic index.html page with a post method), but sends me back a 31 bytes file (instead of 6.1k), with the right name and extension, but absolutely not the right content.

The console log displays:

```
{ upload:
   { domain: null,
    _events: {},
     _maxListeners: 10,
 size: 29526,
 path: '/tmp/bcb357fa7f8e5fcc075964c6bcbbe9bb',
 name: 'hamburg.svg',
 type: 'image/svg+xml',
 hash: null,
 lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 21 2014 11:04:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),
 _writeStream:
  { _writableState: [Object],
    writable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _maxListeners: 10,
    path: '/tmp/bcb357fa7f8e5fcc075964c6bcbbe9bb',
    fd: null,
    flags: 'w',
    mode: 438,
    start: undefined,
    pos: undefined,
    bytesWritten: 29526,
    closed: true } }     }

{ format: 'ttf' }
```

Comment: Could you also add what is expected to appear?

Comment: Also, `res.end(files.upload.path + "." + fields.format);` will send the path of the file, not the file itself. Are you sure you want to do that? Don t you want to send the content?

Comment: Yes, I want to send the file itself. But response.end expects a string or buffer, and I can't see how to do it otherwise.
And, I have on my basic html page a button "submit"to tranfer the file, and I did expect that clicking on this button would send me a download request for the file. And it does send me a file, but 41 bytes, and absolutely not a font file that Fontforge could open.

Comment: 41byte seems to be the path (41 character), you should try to read the file and send the content, not the path. Maybe something with fs.readFile()?

Comment: Indeed, fs.readFile() sends me the raw buffer. But, as well, not converted. But that sure is a step.

Comment: Which file did you read? files.upload.path or `files.upload.path + '.' + fields.format`?

Comment: Problem solved! Using fs.readFile(files.upload.path + "." + fields.format ...) and res.end(data) in the end of the function, it has sent me the file I wanted.
Thanks alot DrakaSAN ;)

Comment: As you are posting your first question, I d like to remind you that for the this website, you are supposed to accept a answer with the green mark next to it. I just (re)posted what had been said in comment. Good day sir : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was that you were sending the path to the converted file. To send the file itself, you need to use:

```
fs.readFile(files.upload.path + '.' + fields.format, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.end('Error: ' + err);
    } else {
        res.end(data);
    }
});
```